# AngularJS XSS in <input> field

Tags: angularjs, xss

I have an AngularJS app (Angular version 1.6.4) that uses an input field to bind an URL (that can be changed by the user) to a model.  Here is how it looks like:

```
<input ng-model="connectorService.url">
```

This URL is then saved to a backend and re-loaded from there as soon as the page is refreshed. I have tried to do some XSS by manipulating the POST requests that set the URL in the backend.

I entered `<script>alert("XSS");</script>` into the input and it is set correctly (verified by manually requesting it from the backend). When I reload the page, the input field contains the XSS but it is not executed. What am I doing wrong? Is there still a sandbox in AngularJS 1.6.4?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there still a sandbox in AngularJS 1.6.4?

No, the expression sandbox was removed with AngularJS 1.6

From the Docs:

> Another major change [with V1.6] is the removal of the **Expression Sandbox**. This should not require changes to your application (and may give it a small performance boost), but we strongly recommend reading the [Sandbox Removal Blog Post](http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/09/angular-16-expression-sandbox-removal.html) to understand the implications behind the removal and whether any action is required on your part.
>
> — [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating to V1.6](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrating-from-1-5-to-1-6)

For additional information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Sandbox Removal](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/security#sandbox-removal)

Comment: But why is my XSS Not executed when there is no sandbox anymore?